# Single word for: innately flawed

Tags: single-word-requests

I am searching for a single word that means something is not just flawed, but innately flawed.

"More’s intentional creation of an **innately flawed** Utopian society shows his..."

Comment: Is it just me or does `flawed Utopian` sound oxymoronic?

Comment: Yes. That is the point. I am writing an essay on Thomas More's "Utopia" book, in which the actual Utopian society is somewhat messed up. In my sentence above, "Utopian" is representative of the name of the ideal society the author writes about. The term utopia was popularized afterwards, and its meaning was misconstrued.

Answer (score 4):

Something that is not just flawed, but innately flawed, is *ill-conceived*.

Dictionary.com:

> [*ill-conceived*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ill-conceived): badly conceived or planned
>
> [*conceive*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/conceive?s=t): to form
>   (a notion, opinion, purpose, etc.); to form a notion or idea of;
>   imagine.

Your example:

> "More’s intentional creation of an *ill-conceived* Utopian society shows
>   his..."

Answer (score 2):

I've thought a while, I suggest:

- Doomed - bleek from the onset
- Malformed - defective in structure
- Defective - bad engineering
- Fallacious - founded on flawed premise

Comment: Welcome to ELU. _Fallacious_ sounds good. Add a reference/citation and then you have my upvote. Check this: [How do I write a good answer?](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You might use **half-baked**, although **ill-conceived** is probably a better match for your needs.

> half-baked: not fully thought through; lacking a sound basis.
>
> "a half-baked conspiracy theory"

Answer (score 0):

[*impossible*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/impossible)

> unable to exist, happen, or be achieved; not possible:

*(Cambridge Dictionary)*